# How do I sync Gmail contacts with my iMac's address book and my iPhone?

Tags: contacts, google-sync

I enable the sync with Google inside the preferences of address book on snow leopard but I don't know how to set the time between the syncing and how to force to update. I added a new contact to gmail from the web browser now I eed this contact in the iPhone and on the iMac too.
Before Lion there was iSync which stay in the status bar and keep update my contacts every time I wanted, but now with Lion it's gone!

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

When I had Snow Leopard I had the Google address book sync enabled and I somehow managed to put a 'sync' icon in the menu bar.

If I remember correctly I added it from the "old" `iSync` application (unsuccessfully trying to sync with a Samsung phone).

Now in Lion I still have it and it allows me to manually force the update of my Google address book, but I can't find how to obtain it as the `iSync` app seems to have disappeared.

[image]

This [article here](http://slashusr.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/the-missing-isync-in-os-x-lion-and-what-to-do-about-it/) describes the situation of iSync in more details

Comment: yes. As I say before the iSync app has been removed by Apple in Lion

Comment: Yes, but in some way I still have it : I still have the icon in the menu bar and I can still force the update

Comment: Are you sure that the icon isn't MobileMe one?
They look like the same

Comment: So I restore the iSync app from an old Snow Leopard's backup, but when I press sync now it ask me for the mobile me account that I don't have I didn't need before Lion! :(

Comment: There's something I don't understand too... I never had any mobile me account, and the preferences for Mobile Me are empty; yet I have this icon and it really does force the sync. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I can't believe that Apple remove this option. So what I have to do for keeping sync the contact between my devices and gcontact?OMG!

Comment: The link in @cedrich answer outlines a way to move iSync into Lion.  I like this tip since I currently use iSync in SL to sync my address book with Gmail contacts and will need a solution if I move to Lion.  Here's another article with comments on this issue.  http://www.macosliontips.com/news/lion-address-book-loses-the-ability-to-sync-with-google-contacts.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to give this a read:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3963741?start=0&tstart=0

The key part would be:

> For AB to send new info immediately (not knowing the time interval), quit AB and restart it. It should update all info. If not, uncheck the sync option in AB prefs, the recheck and reinput the username and password. That should create an immediate sync.

Answer (score 0):

I sync between mac, iphone and gmail (I have google apps for our company, so we can share contacts etc).

The best way to do it is through iTunes as follows:

1. Connect your phone.
2. When iTunes pops up, click the info tab.
3. Make sure "Sync Address book contacts" is selected
4. Click "Sync with Google"
5. Click Configure and enter your gmail username and pass.

That's it. Now whenever your phone syncs (settings you can further control, but not really for this post), your contacts will sync with both google and your address book.